# How to get windspeed when temperature is maximum for each city?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the sample dataset, I have [Weather_Data,](https://github.com/debaonline4u/Python_Programming/blob/master/pandas_and_data_visualization/Pandas_group_by_1/weather_by_cities.csv) 
I want to calculate 
`"What is the windspeed when temperature is maximum for each city"`
I have tried following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('weather_by_cities.csv')
g = df.groupby('city')
g.max()
```

But Instead of getting corresponding Wind Speed, when temperature is maximum, it's giving maximum wind speed along with maximum temperature, which is little annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('weather_by_cities.csv')
max_df = df[['city', 'temperature']].groupby('city').max().reset_index()
pd.merge(max_df, df[['city', 'temperature', 'windspeed']], how='inner', on=['city', 'temperature'])
```

Comment: yes this exactly i wanted.

Comment: can you please suggest some tutorials where i can practice pandas or i can get more information regarding pandas.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should find maximum temperature for each city, then merge it with the main data to find the relative windspeed

```
city_and_max_temp = data.groupby('city').agg('max')[['temperature']]
data.merge( right=city_and_max_temp ,how='inner')[['city','windspeed']]
```

Comment: it also worked. i got the output

Comment: use this: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/python-pandas-cheat-sheet